# How to connect to Mongodb in Apache Airflow?

Tags: mongodb, airflow

I am trying to process data from external source and store it in my MongoDB. So I am trying to understand how should I access Mongodb Hook in my operator.

Comment: We have a collection of airflow operators and hooks we have developed. Including a few for Mongo. Let me check with our engineering directors to see if we can open source them. Otherwise I will post an answer with some code examples.

Comment: Thanks @trejas. I am new to Airflow and found - http://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/mongo_hook.html, but wasn't sure how would I access this in a DAG.

Comment: That must be in 1.10. We have been using 1.9 and created our own. But yes, this is the “best_practice” way to implement an upload or query to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official example for how to use mongo hook from an operator:

https://github.com/airflow-plugins/mongo_plugin/blob/master/operators/s3_to_mongo_operator.py